# How to add a tag to the product listing title?

Tags: liquid

I'm working on a Shopify store and the client requested to add a particular tag (Notes_tag) after the product title on the collection listing page. 
How can I check for this condition (if that particular tag exists) and if so, add it to the product title?

I have tried this:

```
  {% for tag in collection.tags %}
    {% if tag contains 'Notes_' %}
      <h1>Have notes</h1>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to find tag in product not in collection. 
Please try this below code

```
  {% for tag in product.tags %}
    {% if tag contains 'Notes_' %}
      <h1>Have notes</h1>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```